# Setting up Multi Node Hadoop Hortonworks Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, bigdata, hadoop2, hortonworks-data-platform, hortonworks-dataflow

I am working on a proof of concept in hadoop and I am likely to setup a cluster with HDP and HDF hortonwork components.

The volume of data is really small, So the disk volume may not need more than 10 GB for each node if I am not wrong.

What are the criteria's to be considered for the No OF CPU'S and the RAM for the master and slave node?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it looks like you might be doing MapReduce jobs across multiple nodes. 
With my current knowledge, Slave node will run fine with any CPU configuration and 2/4 GB RAM. For Master Node you may acquire a machine with  at least 4-core, single/dual slot CPU, 8 GB RAM.